# cumulative frequency count of identical elements in a vector - matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a trouble find a matlab function/code to do following task

I have a vector C = [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4]

I need resulting vector Y = [1 2 1 2 3 1 2 1]

Comment: Will something like a histogram work? If so, see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html

Comment: It does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function like the following:

```
C = [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4]
Y = zeros(1,length(C))
helper = zeros(1,max(C)) % stores the count for each value

for i=1:length(C)
   helper(C(i)) = helper(C(i))+1; %increases the count for the value in C(i)
   Y(i) = helper(C(i));    
end
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, if you want it in a one-liner, this will work...

```
Y = sum(cumsum(meshgrid(C)==meshgrid(C)',2).*(meshgrid(C)==meshgrid(C)').*eye(length(A)),1);
```

Not the prettiest, but it will work (you can always split it up to make it clearer)

Comment: You should explain how it works, one-liners are very hard to read.